# Python libraries imported in custom module is not recognised globally

Tags: python, module

I created a module called `my_module.py` as follows

```
import pandas as pd

def create_df(text):

    df = <create a dataframe from the text>

    return df
```

In a cell in Jupyter notebook, I can create a dataframe like this

```
from my_module import create_df

txt = 'this is a test'
df = create_df(txt)
```

However, in another cell, when I ran this query

```
pd.DataFrame?
```

It returned

```
Object `pd.DataFrame` not found.
```

Could you please explain what's going on? Shouldn't I include the `import pandas as pd` in `my_module.py` but should declare in a cell of the notebook `import pandas as pd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your notebook you import your module, but you do not write:

`import pandas as pd`

hence `pandas` is not imported, nor is `pd` added to the namespace of your notebook (check `dir()`, you will not see `pd` in your notebook), and so your interpreter has no idea of what a `pd.DataFrame` is.

I think your confusion stems from the fact that you imported `pandas` in your module, and so it will also be imported in your main script or notebook. No, you need to import it again, as any import made in a module does not carry over to the main script.

**EDIT**: To be more specific, in python there is the concept of a namespace, which is a collection of global variables that are associated to a module.

Key concept: each module has its own namespace: `numpy` has one, `pandas` has one, your `main.py` script has one, and they are separated.

When you write `import pandas as pd` in your `my_module.py` for example, you are importing `pandas` as `.pd` in your namespace to your `my_module.py` script. There, and only there, by writing `pd.` you will be able to access the components of your library.

If you now write `from my_module import create_df` in your `main.py` (or notebook in your case), you add `create_df` to the namespace of `main.py`. The `main.py` has no knowledge of the imports done in `my_module.py` because it does not share its namespace, so you cannot use `pd.` here.

Likewise, you cannot `import pandas as pd` in the `main.py` and not in the `my_module.py`, and hope that it will be recognized: you will call `create_df`, it will look for the variables in the `my_modules.py` namespace, not see `.pd` and it will throw an error.

Btw, you can see which variables are loaded in the namespace of your script by using the built-in method `dir(<module_name>)`. By default `dir()` will give you the namespace of the script you called it in, while `dir(pd)` will give you the one of `pandas` (provided of course that `pd` is in the namespace, i.e `import pandas as pd`!)

Hope it is clearer!

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, neko. Do you know why the imported pd wasn't applied globally to the whole notebook? If so, best practice should be NOT importing any libraries in a custom module then?

Comment: Thanks, neko. Your detailed explanation for some newbies like me is much appreciated.